# How can i get the module name in public/index.php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to get the name of the module by adding code in public/index.php. What I have tried on this url:

**localhost/folder_name/public/uk**

```
$requested_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I get this result **folder_name/public/uk** but i dont need this. I need only module name called **uk**

```
$this->getResponse() //not working in this file
```

Any solution?

Comment: Is not like this how zf2 works. Actually all code happened on the module folder, well by default, but you have also vendor folder and you can use your own folder. The index.php should stay as it is. If you need the module name you have to do it on the bootstrap method and then pass it to the layout or view.

Comment: actually I am trying to get different lang on different modules. Is there any way to call with conditions. e.g when I open url localhost/folder_name/public/uk then from languages uk.php will be called. same for australia. Note: when i open url of localhost/folder_name/public/aus then uk.php will not run according to my condition.

Comment: Yes, for that there are routes. Please forget every knowledge of traditional website. Zf2 is an MVC framework therefore everything is really different from traditional websites, I had the same problem when I first start. if you want to use zf2 do everything at the zf2 way, otherwise, just create a traditional website. I am sorry I won't be able to help you but the explanation of routes is too long to explain here :D

Comment: ok thanx but please give me source link where i can easily understand routes

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

Comment: Please don't suggest the legacy documentation links to newcomers. ZF2's documentation is bad (especially it has some really important differences between latest and 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 versions). I strongly recommend to use `latest` version on readthedocs: https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html This

Comment: Thanks foozy it is more simple than the Zend official documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get loaded modules as descriped in your application.config, you can do this:

```
$moduleManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModuleManager');
$modules = $moduleManager->getLoadedModules();
```